# ¿Se puede cambiar la clase de muchas variables a la vez en R?

Tags: r, stata

Necesito exportar un data frame para que otra persona pueda utilizarlo en Stata, para eso necesito que aquellas variable que sean character en R no me las lea como string en Stata. Es por eso que me preguntaba si existe la posibilidad de cambiarle la clase a todas las variables de este tipo por numeric que no sea de forma manual, una por una. Ya que de esta forma funciona:

```
as.numeric(usaid_pry2$year)
```

El data frame que utilizo está en mi repositorio de github: https://github.com/florenciagayraud/usaidpry
Gracias a todos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La forma más simple de convertir a numérico un conjunto de variables/columnas es "aplicar" la función `as.numeric` a cada una de ellas en el caso que correspondiera convertir todas a numéricas:

```
usaid_pry2b <- setNames(data.frame(lapply(usaid_pry2, as.numeric)), 
                        colnames(usaid_pry2))
sum(sapply(usaid_pry2b, is.numeric))
```

Con esto convertimos todas las columnas a numéricas, el `sum` de las columnas numéricas del nuevo `data.frame`, arroja ahora el total de las columnas: 600, pero al convertir, hay un warning: `There were 21 warnings (use warnings() to see them)`, si vemos estos, todos dicen lo mismo: `lapply(usaid_pry2, as.numeric) : NAs introducidos por coerción`. Esto nos está informando que hubo 21 conversiones que se hicieron, pero que había valores en estas columnas que no pudieron convertirse a un número, por lo que fueron reemplazados por un `NA`. Esto es algo que sin duda tendrías que verificarlo antes, puede ser válido que esto ocurra o no.

Una forma menos "cruenta" es intentar convertir cada columna y en caso que no todos los valores puedan ser trasladados a un número, mantener los datos originales. Algo como esto:

```
try_convert <- function(x, classname) {
  tmp <- x
  tryCatch({
    suppressWarnings(class(tmp) <- classname)
    tmp
  }
  )
}

usaid_pry2b <- setNames(data.frame(lapply(usaid_pry2, try_convert, "numeric")), 
                        colnames(usaid_pry2))
sum(sapply(usaid_pry2b, is.numeric))
[579]
```

Finalmente, vemos que tenemos 579 columnas numéricas, es decir las 600 originales menos las 21 que deberíamos revisar.

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio, la segunda explicación me sirvió a la perfección!!